# Android Studio Unknown Emulator running and can't be terminated

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

I have one emulator actively running at the moment but I see two emulators running when I run the app. One of them is an Unknown Emulator.
When I choose the Unknown emulator, the console shows this error:
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
How do I terminate this Unknown Simulator? I think it's using my system's resources and degrading the performance.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Well, it was the BlueStacks emulator running in the background. Android Studio automatically detects it. The unknown simulator was there because BlueStacks was running in the background at the Notification Tray in my windows 8.1 
When I closed BlueStacks from the Notification Tray, the Unknown emulator vanished for good.

Answer (score 2):

**First reason if your emulator in offline.**
To resolve this you need to run command kill-server from adb.

Open Command prompt->navigate to android sdk-> go to platform-tools-> adb kill-server -> adb start-server

You need to run above command to remove unknown

**Second reason if your project configuration not match with emulator configuration**

Change your emulator configuration with your project requirement. May be your application version not match with emulator configuration

Comment: I just ran those commands a few times, but didn't work. I killed the Unknown Emulator's process in the AVD monitor but it keeps coming back. No changes even if I restarted PC and android studio both. And I'm sure the project configuration is alright.

Comment: This is correct answer. Just restart ADB and all hanging emulators will be gone. Upvote

Answer (score 2):

It was very simple to fix for my case :) Just need to type the following 2 commands using CMD:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

[image]
Make sure that the windows PATH variable contains "adb.exe" file's directory location. Normally, it should be:

```
YOUR_PATH_TO_SDK\platform-tools
//For example: D:\sdk\platform-tools
```